# Create global key command to launch app OSX

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, automator

I'm looking to set a global key command that will launch my app when pressed. I know this can be done manually using Automator... I'm looking to have my app ask if the user would like this on first time startup, and then *do it for them*. Is there any way to set up an automator service programmatically, in swift or objective-c?

Comment: Sounds like you could accomplish this with SMLoginItem (Service Management framework allowing you to boot on login) and https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut which allows you to assign a global hotkey to do anything.

Comment: Even just getting the boot on login functionality in is a headache! Thanks for the pointers.